# literal charT array

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, string-literals

I'm working on some API for algorithm involving text.

I would like to make it NOT dependent on the character type (`char`,`wchar_t`...), so I have made template classes with a template parameter CharT.
These classes use `std::basic_string<CharT>`.

I have to initialize a lot of basic_string with default values.
If `CharT` is `char` I can affect the literal "default_text", or if CharT is `wchar_t` I can affect L"default_text", but this is not generic (it is `CharT` dependant).

Do you think of any way to initialize the basic_string with a generic method ?

If that may help, my code is in `C++11`.

Comment: You can write helper function with specializations, that will return needed literal.

Comment: Why do you need a default value?

Comment: ForEver, I thought of that solution but this is quite verbose since there is a lot of default values.

Comment: Holt, default values are for default behaviour of virtual methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code is generic, I guess that the literal you have only contains ASCII characters. Otherwise, you'd have to transcode it on the fly which is going to be a lot of hassle. In order to promote a pure-ASCII string literal of type `char[]` to another character type, you can simply promote each character individually.

If you're going to initialize a `std::basic_string` anyway, you can as well do it right away.  The following function takes a `char[]` string literal and a target type and promotes it to a string of that type.

```
template <typename CharT>
auto
as_string(const char *const text)
{
  const auto length = std::strlen(text);
  auto string = std::basic_string<CharT> {};
  string.resize(length);
  for (auto i = std::size_t {}; i < length; ++i)
    string[i] = CharT {text[i]};
  return string;
}
```

It can be used like this.

```
std::cout << as_string<char>("The bats are in the belfry") << '\n';
std::wcout << as_string<wchar_t>("The dew is on the moor") << L'\n';
```

But you've asked for a character array, not a `std::basic_string`. In C++14, `constexpr` can help a lot with this.  Be warned that you'd need the most recent compilers for this to be supported well.

The first thing we'll have to do is rolling our own version of `std::array` that provides `constexpr` operations.  You can get as fancy as you want to but I'll keep it simple here.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array { T data[N]; };
```

Next, we also need a `constexpr` version of `std::strlen`.

```
template <typename CharT>
constexpr auto
cstrlen(const CharT *const text) noexcept
{
  auto length = std::size_t {};
  for (auto s = text; *s != CharT {0}; ++s)
    ++length;
  return length;
}
```

Now we can write a `constexpr` function that promotes us a string literal.

```
template <typename CharT, std::size_t Length>
constexpr auto
as_array(const char *const text)
{
  auto characters = array<CharT, Length + 1> {};
  if (cstrlen(text) != Length)
    throw std::invalid_argument {"Don't lie about the length!"};
  for (auto i = std::size_t {}; i < Length; ++i)
    characters.data[i] = text[i];
  characters.data[Length] = CharT {0};
  return characters;
}
```

It might be convenient to wrap it into a macro.  I'm sorry for that.

```
#define AS_ARRAY(Type, Text) as_array<Type, cstrlen(Text)>(Text).data
```

It can be used like this.

```
std::cout << AS_ARRAY(char, "The bats are in the belfry") << '\n';
std::wcout << AS_ARRAY(wchar_t, "The dew is on the moor") << L'\n';
```

Comment: Interesting choice of test strings :-)

Comment: Thanks, really interresting answer, I have learned a lot (I didn't even know that size_t was defined in std, I always use it without prefix and my compiler does not yell).

Comment: @phausy It is defined in `<cstddef>` which – on most implementations – drags in `<stddef.h>` and the latter has the `typedef`s in the global `namespace`.